# How can I filter by dates in a web page where the url does not include date in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I need to bring the data from the following website:

http://ido.xm.com.co/ido/SitePages/despacho.aspx

Then, I noticed that a request is made to the following url in order to fetch the data:

[http://serviciossistemareportes.xm.com.co/ido/XmService.svc/despachorecurso](http://serviciossistemareportes.xm.com.co/ido/XmService.svc)

Then I simply make the request to fetch them:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://serviciossistemareportes.xm.com.co/ido/XmService.svc/despachorecurso"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
```

So far so good. But I also need to get the data from previous dates and in the application I don't see any parameter that allows me to filter by dates. How can I do it?